# Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr' Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Here is the code that is causing the error

```
<div class ="container">
  <div class = "card">
      <h3 class="text-center"> Courses List</h3>
      <div class = "card-body">
          <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <th scope="col">code</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">description</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor = "let courses of course">
                  <td>{{ courses.coursecode }}</td>
                  <td>{{ courses.coursename }}</td>
                  <td>{{ courses.description }}</td>
                </tr> 
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I looked around online for solutions and most had to do with improper imports of BrowserModule and CommonModule however I have both of these imported in the app.module file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomePageComponent } from './components/home-page/home-page.component';
import { NavBarComponent } from './components/nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
import { PlannedCoursesPageComponent } from './components/planned-courses-page/planned-courses-page.component';
import { ProgressPageComponent } from './components/progress-page/progress-page.component';
import { CalendarModule, DateAdapter } from 'angular-calendar';
import { adapterFactory } from 'angular-calendar/date-adapters/date-fns';
import { TermCalendarComponent } from './components/planned-courses-page/term-calendar/term-calendar.component';
import { CourseListComponent } from './components/planned-courses-page/course-list/course-list.component';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './components/login-page/login-page.component';
import { CourseCatalogPageComponent } from './components/course-catalog-page/course-catalog-page.component';
import { MessagingCenterPageComponent } from './components/messaging-center-page/messaging-center-page.component';
import { AdviseesPageComponent } from './components/advisees-page/advisees-page.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { courseService } from './service/course-service.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomePageComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    PlannedCoursesPageComponent,
    ProgressPageComponent,
    TermCalendarComponent,
    CourseListComponent,
    LoginPageComponent,
    CourseCatalogPageComponent,
    MessagingCenterPageComponent,
    AdviseesPageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CalendarModule.forRoot({ provide: DateAdapter, useFactory: adapterFactory })
  ],
  providers: [courseService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the full error that I am getting

```
NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr' (used in the 'CourseListComponent' component template).
1. If 'tr' is an Angular component and it has the 'ngForOf' input, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

I am pretty new to angular so any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Do you have the component in the declarations array of the `AppModule`?

Comment: Is it a typo? "let courses of course"? Do you mean "let course of courses"?

Comment: Agreed with @Flo, though, I know at times you may see an error even though it should be fine. Did you try rebuilding, assuming the identifier accessed is correct?